# How to declare an NSString with multiple possible values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

I want to declare an NSString object to use within an alert, but its actual content depends on various factors, determined by some variable. I'm wondering how best to approach this. In most cases I've done something like this:

```
- (void)info {
    NSString *targetString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    switch (self.target) {
        case 1:
            targetString = @"ONE";
            break;
        case 2:
            targetString = @"TWO";
            break;
        case 3:
            targetString = @"THREE";
            break;
        default:
            targetString = @"";
            break;
    }

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Text: %@", targetString]; 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Info"
                          message:message 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok!" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.tag = kInfoAlert;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [targetString release];
    [message release];
}
```

However when I run this through the build analyser, I get messages telling me the string is leaking memory:

First of all it says:

> Value stored to 'targetString' during
>   its initialization is never read

Then:

> Potential leak of an object allocated
>   on line 137 and stored into
>   'targetString'

These 2 comments are at line 136 and 137, where line 136 is

`NSString *targetString = [[NSString alloc] init];`

An alternative might be to declare the string as

```
NSString *targetString;
```

and set it in each case as

```
targetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ONE"];
```

etc

Or even allocing the String in each case in order to release it at the end...

Well, what would be the best approach here?

Thanks,

Michael :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for your memory leak is because you are needlessly allocating a string with this line

```
NSString *targetString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

and then setting it to a literal object. Define targetString as nil because when you set it to another value like `targetString = @"ONE"` you are no longer referencing the empty string you allocated and that causes a memory leak. As for your approach of the switch case for determining the value that is fine.

Comment: So I should just declare it as NSString *targetString, and then set it like targetString = @"ONE" ?

Comment: No declare it as nil. `NSString *targetString = nil;` and then set it to a literal in the switch statement. Also there is no need to release the targetString when setting it to a string.

Comment: What about if the string I'm setting isn't a simple literal, i.e. I need to declare something like [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Some text plus %@", someString]; Then I'm allocating the memory. Should I instead use a convenience method?

Comment: Yes I would recommend using `+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be enough:

```
NSString *targetString = nil;
```

And you don't need to release targetString then.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead of the switch:

```
- (NSString*) stringForIndex: (NSUInteger) index
{
    NSParameterAssert(index < 4);
    id strings[] = {@"none", @"one", @"two", @"three"};
    return strings[index];
}
```

Comment: In this case yes, but I was just using that to illustrate a more general case. Thanks though.